# Dropping unique constraint in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a unique constraint.  What is the right way to drop that constraint?

The particular index doesn't have a name. It just has a column name.

And I want to keep the column....just drop the uniqueness constraint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you haven't specified a name for the index in your DDL, MySQL will chose a name. Execute the following statement:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE foobar\G
```

There are several ways to drop the constraint, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE foobar DROP INDEX index_name;
```